# custom validation gives blank field after validation which is not right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a custom validation in my model like this:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    #VIRTUAL ATTRIBUTES
    attr_accessor :start_date, :start_time, :duration

    #RELATIONSHIPS
    belongs_to :task

    #VALIDATIONS
    before_validation :convert_to_datetime
    before_validation :dur
    validates :duration, presence: true
    validate :is_date_nil
    validate :time_collision_validation, if: :is_appointments_not_empty
    validate :check_time
    after_save :save_start_date

    def is_appointments_not_empty
        Appointment.all.present? 
    end

    def check_time  
        start_at = Time.parse("#{@start_date} #{@start_time}") 
        if start_at < Time.now
            errors.add(:start_date, "Cannot input past times")
        end
    end

    def convert_to_datetime
        unless @start_date.blank? && @start_time.blank? 
            self.start_at = Time.parse("#{@start_date} #{@start_time}")         
        end
    end

    def dur
        if @start_date.present? && @start_time.present? && @duration.present?
            self.end_at = Time.parse("#{@start_date} #{@start_time}") + (@duration.to_f*60*60)
        end
    end

    def time_collision_validation
        appointments = Appointment.all


        if @start_date.present? && @start_time.present? && duration == 0.to_s
            start_at = Time.parse("#{@start_date} #{@start_time}") 
            end_at = Time.parse("#{@start_date} #{@start_time}") + (@duration.to_f*60*60)
            appointments.each do |a|
                if start_at <= a.end_at - (2*60*60) && start_at >= a.start_at - (1*60*60)
                    errors.add(:start_time)
                    errors.add(:start_date, "An appointment already 
                        exists at #{a.start_at.strftime("%I:%M%p")} of #{a.start_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")} 
                        to #{a.end_at.strftime("%I:%M%p")} of #{a.end_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}. 
                        Please select a different date or time.")

                    break

                end
            end

        elsif @start_date.present? && @start_time.present? && duration.present?
            start_at = Time.parse("#{@start_date} #{@start_time}") 
            end_at = Time.parse("#{@start_date} #{@start_time}") + (@duration.to_f*60*60)
            appointments.each do |a|
                if start_at <= a.end_at - (2*60*60) && a.start_at <= end_at 
                    errors.add(:start_time)
                    errors.add(:start_date, "An appointment already 
                        exists at #{a.start_at.strftime("%I:%M%p")} of #{a.start_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")} 
                        to #{a.end_at.strftime("%I:%M%p")} of #{a.end_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}. 
                        Please select a different date or time.")
                    break
                end
            end
        end

    end


    def is_date_nil
        if @start_date.blank? && @start_time.blank?
            errors.add(:start_date,  "Start date can't be blank")
            errors.add(:start_time,  "Start time can't be blank")
        end

        if @start_date.blank? && @start_time.present?
            errors.add(:start_date,  "Start date can't be blank")
        end

        if  @start_time.blank? && @start_date.present?
            errors.add(:start_time,  "Start time can't be blank")
        end
    end


    def start_date=(date)
        @start_date = Date.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y") if date.present?
    end
    # def save_start_date
    #   @start_date = Date.strptime(@start_date, "%d/%m/%Y") if @start_date.present?
    # end

    # def save_start_date
    #   @start_date = Date.parse(@start_date).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")if @start_date.present?

    # end

    def start_time=(time)
        @start_time = Time.parse(time).strftime("%H:%M:%S") if time.present?
    end

    def duration=(duration)
        @duration = duration if duration.present?
    end

    # def start_date
    #       @start_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") if start_at.present?  # || start_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") if start_at.present? 
    #   end 

    def start_date
        unless @start_date.blank?
            @start_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        end
        # start_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") if start_at.present? 
    end 

    def start_time
        @start_time || start_at.strftime("%I:%M%p") if start_at.present? 
    end


    # def duration
    #   @duration || 9
    # end

end
```

After this time_collision_validation executes, the value fields are blank which I don't want because I'm concerned with UX. ie: start_date and start_time fields are blank.

When I checked the value attribute in input in the HTML source code, the value contains a date string. I wonder why it does not show in the field.

Can somebody help me with this and explain what is going on please? >.<

Answer (score 0):

```
validate :time_collision_validation

def time_collision_validation
  appointments = Appointment.all
  if self.start_date.present? && self.start_time.present? && duration.present?
    start_at = Time.parse("#{self.start_date} #{self.start_time}") 
    end_at = Time.parse("#{self.start_date} #{self.start_time}") + (self.duration.to_f.hours)
    appointments.each do |appointment|
      if duration == 0.to_s
        duration_ok = start_at >= appointment.start_at - (1.hours) 
      else
        duration_ok = appointment.start_at <= end_at
      end
      if start_at <= appointment.end_at - (2.hours) && duration_ok
        errors.add(:start_time)
        errors.add(:start_date, "An appointment already 
          exists at #{appointment.start_at.strftime("%I:%M%p")} of #{appointment.start_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")} 
          to #{appointment.end_at.strftime("%I:%M%p")} of #{appointment.end_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}. 
          Please select a different date or time.")
        break
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Notes:

- you variously refer to `duration` and `self.duration`.  For readability i would always use `self.duration` rather than `duration` or `self.duration` as it makes it clear to the reader that you are talking about  a method/field of the current object rather than a local variable.  I've change all instances of referencing methods/fields of the current object to `self.methodname`
- you had a lot of repetition shared between the two if cases.  I've refactored these to avoid repetition.
- `2*60*60` is like saying `2.hours` and the latter is much more readable.
- what are start_date and start_time - are they strings or date/time objects?
- rather than loading every appointment in your entire database, and cycling through them, it would be much more efficient to just search for a single colliding other appointment.  if you find one then you can add the errors.  I was tempted to do this here but it's not clear exactly what's going on with your database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I put all the codes in that model if you want to take a look please. In my field I have created virtual attributes start time and start date then in my model Im combining these 2 to save it in my database. Its not just clear why does the value not retain after the custom validation executes

Comment: Is that still the case when you use my version?

Comment: hi, I used your version, the values are still not showing in the field after validation. Anyway, I tried a simple custom validation, see my code, I have custom validation called check_time. its giving same result (not showing value in field). I dont knwo what to do now. I have a feeling the problem could be in setting my virtual atr but not so sure. Thank you for your reply.